# Using Pug with Typescript

Tags: typescript, express, pug

In a `.pug` file I need to reference a typescript file which is not possible (MIME type video/mp2t error). What is the best practice here? To first compile typescript to javascript and reference js file in `pug` file? If so, what would be the script for this?

Another problem is if I compile typescript to `dist` folder first, then `pug` file will be unavailable there, so I'll get a different error.

This is my pug file right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Autocomplete!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/autocomplete.css">
    <script src="/javascripts/autocomplete.ts"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <p>
        <input name="country">
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I compile it first then should I move `pug` file in a `dist` folder? I would also move `css` files there as well?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: In the past I've just compiled the TypeScript to the same directory, and used the same reference to the file, but ending in .js instead of .ts. Keep in mind this works when you compile to the same directory, not a separate one.